# Visual Studio Code doesn't arise scope error in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am learning and testing scopes in C# using VS Code. But for my surprise VS Code doesn't arise warning/error about variable '***message***' is not in desired scope.
Here's the file:

```
using System;

    public class TestScope
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int score = 100;

            if (score >= 50)
                string message = "Good score";  // Declared in if statement

            Console.WriteLine(message);         // Variable unavailable
        }
    }
```

I have extention C# v1.17.1 by Microsoft installed and file is correctly recognized by VS Code. I wander am I missing some extention or something is not set up correctly. Any help?

Comment: So it compiles? What's the output when you run it?

Comment: Try to restart Omnisharp `Ctrl+Shift+P` then type `Restart OmniSharp`

Comment: I just made a test. Since now it was just a one file in random folder. Now I made C# project in Visual Studio and copied my code into program.cs file. Now VS code show the errors. There must be something what I have not learn yet, why this happens. Btw, same situation also in Visual Studio 2017 - if single file, no errors, if project I get errors.